# Is there a multivalued field type available in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, database-design, types, multivalue

I want to know if it is possible to store multiple values in a field in PostgreSQL.

I have a table called `Token` with the columns `id`, `text` and `category`. `category` is a multivalued field. Is it necessary to create a separate table for it or is there a way to store it in the `Token` table?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/arrays.html) in PostgreSQL. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "token" (
  "id"       integer PRIMARY KEY,
  "text"     text,
  "category" text[]
);
```

Now you can insert multiple categories for each row into `token`:

```
INSERT INTO "token" ("id", "text", "category")
VALUES (1, 'some text', ARRAY['cate1', 'cate2']);
```

You can find the rows like:

```
SELECT * FROM "token" WHERE 'cate1' = ANY ("category");
```

Comment: If I do a query like `SELECT * FROM token WHERE category = 'cate1'`, the query will search inside the array?

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição No, you can use `@>` operator or [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16871) hyperoperator instead.

Answer (score 13):

There are several:

- [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)
- [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html) (associative tables)
- [composite types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) (similar to structs in C, more or less)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question had been asked 10 years ago but since Postgres is evolving there are new types that are optimized and could be used to address this issue

1. [json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)
2. [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT) aka binary json

Comment: Even though JSON fields are way more flexible in terms of performance are not as good as multi-value fields. This is due to some indexing limitations. As always it depends on each case and your needs in every use case you implement.